# Variable values not changing inside a loop after geocoding

Tags: javascript

THe following code loops through a JSON array which contains 2 values - city_name and counter and places a pin on the map.

I am trying to display the city_name and counter on an info popup on the Google map, but the variables dont change after the first loop.

e.g. The last item in the JSON is Blackpool, but on all loops it remains Blackpool and will always be Blackpool.

```
function initMap() {
        var resultsNonJSON = document.getElementsByName('tbResults')[0].value;
        var jsonResults = JSON.parse(resultsNonJSON);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var myLatLng = {lat: 53.810066, lng: -1.776427};
        var votes;
        var town;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), {
            center: {lat: 54.636633, lng: -2.952166},
            zoom: 6
        });

        for(var i = 0; i  < jsonResults.length; i++) {
            var obj = jsonResults[i];
            town = obj.city_name;

            geocoder.geocode({'address': obj.city_name.concat(", UK")}, function(results, status) { 
                if (status == 'OK') 
                {
                    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<div id="siteNotice"></div>'+
                        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + town + '</h1>'+
                        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>';

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: contentString
                    });

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        title: obj.city_name,
                        icon: {
                            url: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
                        }
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
                else 
                {
                  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }                   
    }
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Also if I was to show the i value, it will always be 7. It seems to stop changing the variables after the geocode is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling an Asynchronous code inside an array loop. In your case,

**geocode** is an Asynchronous function, and the result that you get in the callback function might be delayed for several reasons, and also this is not predictable.

There are various solutions to fix this.

1. One way to fix this is to use let scoped variable instead of var in your for loop if you are using ES6. See the example below.

```js
 

   let list = ['Canada', 'US', 'Japan', 'Mexico'];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  geoCode(list[i], function(index) {
    createMarker(list[i]); // test the value (let vs var)
  });
}

function geoCode(item, cb) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb(item);
  }, 4000);

}

function createMarker(i) {
  console.log(i);

}
```

In your case, just change

```
for(var i = 0; i  < jsonResults.length; i++)
```

to

```
for(let i = 0; i  < jsonResults.length; i++)
```

and move **town** variable inside the loop

```
 for (let i = 0; i < jsonResults.length; i++) {
                var obj = jsonResults[i];

                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': obj.city_name.concat(", UK") }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                        town = jsonResults[i].city_name;
```

2. Next solution is to use closure inside the loop. We need to wrap your async function with anonymous IIFE.

   ```
       (function (town) {

           geocoder.geocode({ 'address': obj.city_name.concat(", UK") }, function (results, status) {
               if (status == 'OK') {
                   var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                       '<div id="siteNotice"></div>' +
                       '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + town + '</h1>' +
                       '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                       '</div>' +
                       '</div>';

                   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                       content: contentString
                   });

                   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: results[0].geometry.location,
                       map: map,
                       title: obj.city_name,
                       icon: {
                           url: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
                       }
                   });
                   marker.addListener('click', function () {
                       infowindow.open(map, marker);
                   });
               }
               else {
                   alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
               }
           });

       })(town);
   ```

Comment: that makes sense as to why it happens, although changing it to let did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Use my second solution where I have just added two lines of codes at the very beginning and at the end. You need to use the closure. This will work.

Comment: I also updated my solution 1. I tested both solutions, and they worked.

Comment: Thanks. I went with solution 1 in the end, works perfectly.